# How to address the customer who is kept on hold over the phone?

Tags: sentence-construction

Once I return to the call, what should I say to the customer?

- Thank you for patiently waiting
- Thank you for being on hold
- Thank you for holding

Which is the best choice?

Answer (score 2):

I would choose "Thank you for holding". "Thank you for patiently waiting sounds condescending.  They may not have been at all patient. "Thank you for being on hold" sounds like "Thank you for having brown hair" or "Thank you for being named Bob" They were on hold because you put them on on hold and they don't deserve thanks for something beyond their control. And don't expected them to say "You're welcome". Just get to the business at hand as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say
Thank you for waiting. Not that holding seems wrong.